# How to modify weights during inference

Tags: tensorflow

I am working to model neural network operation in the presence of faults in the memory. I want to access the weight data to corrupt the bits in the weights during inference, and I want to corrupt them differently for every new activation, so it can't be done offline. How do I access and write to the weights during inference?

I am using the vgg16 model from the `models` repo, which is written using the TF-Slim API (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/vgg.py), I have reproduced a snippet here:

```
with tf.variable_scope(scope, 'vgg_a', [inputs]) as sc:
    end_points_collection = sc.original_name_scope + '_end_points'
    # Collect outputs for conv2d, fully_connected and max_pool2d.
    with slim.arg_scope([slim.conv2d, slim.max_pool2d], 
                        outputs_collections=end_points_collection):
        net = slim.repeat(inputs, 1, slim.conv2d, 64, [3, 3], scope='conv1')
        net = slim.max_pool2d(net, [2, 2], scope='pool1')
```

For example, I want to inject errors in the `slim.conv2d` layers by accessing the trainable and non-trainable variables, making some modifications to their values, and writing them back.

How do I access the instances of the `conv2d` layers before the input is processed?

Can I read `layer.variables`, modify them, and then set the new values back to `layer.variables`?

Or is the right way to do this to subclass `slim.conv2d` and add accessors that allow me to write to the `layer.variables` property?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to inject errors [...] by accessing the trainable and non-trainable variables, making some modifications to their values, and writing them back.

Take a look at this function called `tf.get_variable`: [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable)

`tf.get_variable` gets an existing variable with the specified parameters or creates a new one.

---

First off, naming is important when using variables in Tensorflow. When a variable is declared inside a scope, like the code in your example:

```
with tf.variable_scope(scope, 'vgg_a', [inputs]) as sc:
    [...]
```

The name of the variable becomes dependent on scope `vgg_a`.

For example:

```
def conv_relu(input, kernel_shape, bias_shape):
    # Create variable named "weights".
    weights = tf.get_variable("weights", kernel_shape,
        initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
    # Create variable named "biases".
    biases = tf.get_variable("biases", bias_shape,
        initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input, weights,
        strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    return tf.nn.relu(conv + biases)
```

If I have a helper method that is creating variables like the code above, and call this method in a scope hierarchy like so:

```
def my_image_filter(input_images):
    with tf.variable_scope("conv1"):
        relu1 = conv_relu(input_images, [5, 5, 32, 32], [32])
```

variables created here will be named `conv1/weights`, `conv1/biases`.

```
    with tf.variable_scope("conv2"):
        return conv_relu(relu1, [5, 5, 32, 32], [32])
```

And variables created here will be named `conv2/weights`, `conv2/biases`.

---

With that in mind, lets dive into using variables in Tensorflow:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.variable_scope("foo", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
    a = tf.get_variable(name='a', shape=[1, 10], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(5))

print(a)

with tf.variable_scope("foo", reuse=True):
    b = tf.get_variable(name='a', shape=[1, 10])

print(b)
```

this prints the following lines:

```
<tf.Variable 'foo/a:0' shape=(1, 10) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'foo/a:0' shape=(1, 10) dtype=float32_ref>
```

Hmm, interesting. Both variables have the same name.

Now lets try to see what they contain:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    val_a = sess.run(a)
    val_b = sess.run(b)

print("val_a:", val_a)
print("val_b:", val_b)
```

and we get the following output:

```
val_a: [[5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]]
val_b: [[5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]]
```

Nice! We didn't specify any initializer when we called `tf.get_variable(name='a', shape=[1, 10])` for `b`, but we get the same values as `a`.

Now, just to double check that both `a` and `b` refer to the same variable, lets add this code:

```
new_val = np.array([[2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.]])
assign_op = b.assign(new_val)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(assign_op)
    val_a = sess.run(a)
    val_b = sess.run(b)

print("val_a:", val_a)
print("val_b:", val_b)
```

That prints:

```
val_a: [[2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2.]]
val_b: [[2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2.]]
```

Great! We now know how to find Variables using its scope and name like how you would find files by directory and filename. Then we can manipulate the values using either variable.

---

Likewise, for your problem, you can retrieve a variable that was already initialized and change it however you wish. Just make sure to set `reuse=True` in your scope or call `scope.reuse_variables()`.

[Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables) is a good tutorial on using variables in Tensorflow.